# Sync Gateway - Get information about all the document whose revision-id changed during syncing

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, offlineapps, couchbase-sync-gateway

I would like to know is there is a way to know whether a document with new revision-id is synced in pouch DB. As for know, I am only able to know that new document is Synced.

What I mean, is that whenever a new document is written in pouch DB, I should get the information about all the document which has got affected.

IS there is any way to get this information?

I am using couchbase server, SyncGateway,PouchDB.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you want the [changes](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes) feed. Is that not quite what you need?

Comment: through change feed, I am only able to know that new document has been written in pouch DB.But I want to know which document has been written,is there is any way to find this.

Comment: The changes feed does tell you which documents are written. It even includes the entire document if you request it.